# Azure VM failed to join the Azure AD Domain

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I was joining my VMs with Azure AD Domain and it was successful up to `X` number of VMs.
Now I'm getting following error.
`Your computer could not be joined to the domain. You have exceeded the maximum number of computer accounts you are allowed to create in this domain. Contact your system administrator to have this reset or increased`.

I know how we can fix this issue [on-prem](https://www.niallbrady.com/2019/02/21/how-to-fix-exceeded-the-maximum-number-of-computer-accounts-allowed-to-create-in-this-domain/) AD but don't know how I can fix this on Azure AD Domain.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You could set this in your Azure portal:
**Azure Active Directory** -> **Devices** -> **Device settings**.

[image]

> Note: By default, Azure Active Directory enforces a limit of 15
>   devices for any user object to join. It even enforces this limit on
>   privileged users, like users with the Global Admin role.

Comment: No luck even with the above suggested change.

Comment: Just for information: As of today, Microsoft doesn't have a solution for this and workaround is if you hit the limit create another user, which is awful when you want to join `xxx` number of VMs automatically (automation in place) and you have to change username after every 10 VMs enrollment.

Comment: Sorry for this, please directly create a support request in the Azure portal, it will help you. How to make a support request in the Azure portal, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).